# Solving a system of linear congruences.

Tags: number-theory

Hi I was wondering if you guys can help me out, I'm trying to find all the solutions for:

$ x \equiv 2 (\textrm{mod}\ 10)$
and
$ x \equiv 12 (\textrm{mod}\ 15)$

I don't know how to solve it, since it doesn't follow the chinese remainder theorem, if you guys could help, it would be awesome. 
Thanks

Comment: Use prime factorization to get four congruences.

Answer (score 2):

First we look for a particular solution $c$ of this system: so we have
$$c=2+10u=12+15v\iff 2u-3v=2$$
we take $u=4$ and $v=2$ and then $c=42$. *(You can also take $u=1$ and $v=0$ and then $c=12$)*.

Now we have $30=\operatorname{lcm}(10,15)$ hence the solutions of this system are
$$x=c+30k,\quad k\in \Bbb Z$$

**Remark** To explain why notice that
$$x=c+10u=c+15v\iff x-c=10u=15v$$
hence $10$ and $15$ divide $x-c$ so $30$ also divides $x-c$ hence $x-c=30k$. The converse is trivial i.e. if $x=c+30k$ then $x$ is solution of this system.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $x=15\cdot(2k)+12$ then you have solution.